# Error: 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range' while read big size byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, asp.net-mvc, byte

In API call I am getting byte array as a response. File size of byte array is approx 5gb.
After getting response, when I am trying to read it by..

```
<objHttpResponseMessage>.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result
```

I am getting error **'Array dimensions exceeded supported range.'**

I have tried **gcAllowVeryLargeObjects** but it doesn't worked.

```
<configuration>  
  <runtime>  
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />  
  </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

**Instead of byte array, can we do with stream. If yes plz suggest with example/reference**
Please suggest options..

Comment: See the "Remarks" section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element. The number of elements in an array is limited to Uint32.MaxValue which makes the maximum size of a byte array is about 4 GB

Comment: We don't have the exact types, but generally, for such huge files, you'll want to work over them with streams. Possibly buffered. Don't know about your use case either, but > 4 Gb can fill a system's memory quite fast, you might want to save it on disk first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a memory stream to read the response one byte at a time.

```cs
using System.Threading;

// ...

var stream = <objHttpResponseMessage>.Content.CreateContentReadStream(CancellationToken.None);
int buffer;

do {
  buffer = stream.ReadByte();
  // buffer is -1 if the stream is fully read, otherwise it's the current byte
} while (buffer >= 0);
```